# Trim a string with an array list

Tags: php

I want to be able to trim a string where values match an array like this

```
$image_formats = array('.png','.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif');
$file = 'image1.png';

$file_stripped = trim($file, $image_formats);
```

Wanted Result: `'image1'`

Is there a function for this, whats the best method to go about achieving this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php in addition u can also use in_array() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str_replace` passing an array of search values:

```
$image_formats = array('.png','.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif');
$file = 'image1.png';

$file_stripped = str_replace($image_formats, '', $file);
```

Answer (score 1):

`trim()` is for removing matches of individual characters, not longer strings.

You can convert `$image_formats` to a regular expression and use `preg_replace()`.

```
$image_formats = '/\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/';
$file_stripped = preg_replace($image_formats, '', $file);
```